# If a site has no input then can it be hackable?

Tags: web-application, webserver

If I made a website without any input box can Hackers still hack my site?

Comment: The answer is yes, it is possible.

Comment: The content of an "input box" is not the only thing that is sent to your server. There are many, many other things that are always sent to even see the site.

Comment: GET and POST requests count as input, and therefore possible attack surface. As do, say, SSH of FTP ports that are internet-facing.

Comment: As we have mentioned in your other answers, what do you mean by "hack"? Please always define what this means.

Comment: it IS immune to XSS and SQLi, the two most common attacks. beyond that, we can't speculate.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is all sites can be hacked.

The site is on a server and that server is connected to the internet and as such can be hacked. With that being said keeping your server up to date and properly configured drastically reduces the chances of a compromise.